# Received memory warning in UIImagePickerController didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

After lots of experiment and after lots of suggestion still I am unable to fix this issue. If I take around 5 to 6 picture  using UIImagePickerController Camera or library, I am starting to get Received memory warning in the Xcode log and after then when I try to take 8th or 9th picture the app Crashes.

If anybody solved this issue, please help me out to solve this issue.

Comment: What are you doing with each picture after it is captured? Show us some code.

Comment: check in Instrument which memory are not free?.. Check how meny live bytes are present.